# App Registration not showing as Cloud App on AAD Conditional Access

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-security

I'm creating an app registration for Azure AD using my admin account (specifically for Mobile and desktop applications authentication). I intend to create an AAD Conditional Access that will be applied to the created app registration. For some reason the App Registration is not visible on the cloud app selection when I am trying to select it.

[Screenshot - Conditional Access > Policy > Cloud apps or actions > Select apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqeuS.png)

P.S. It showed on the cloud apps when I tried adding a "Web" platform on the app registration, but still CA is not applied when trying to login using the App Registration. Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot - AAD - Sign-Ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekG2p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the CA policy is applied when a client calls a service. It's not applied directly to a client (public/native) application.

See the **Note** tip [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-cloud-apps#other-applications).

> Since Conditional Access policy sets the requirements for accessing a
> service you are not able to apply it to a client (public/native)
> application. Other words the policy is not set directly on a client
> (public/native) application, but is applied when a client calls a
> service. For example, a policy set on SharePoint service applies to
> the clients calling SharePoint. A policy set on Exchange applies to
> the attempt to access the email using Outlook client. That is why
> client (public/native) applications are not available for selection in
> the Cloud Apps picker and Conditional Access option is not available
> in the application settings for the client (public/native) application
> registered in your tenant.

It also explains why CA is not applied when you tried to login using the App Registration -- you didn't call a service.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question, but is there a way for this to work? To apply CA whenever I login using the app registration I created? What does it mean when you said/it said "You didn't call a service"? Thanks!

Comment: @Esa Calling a service means you acquire an access token to call some API (eg. Microsoft Graph, SharePoint rest API). If you just use this app registration for login, the policy is not applied.

Comment: This answer looks absolutely wrong to me. If you create an app registration for doing OpenID connect in a web application, there is not client or service, it just an app registration for a web app. Same thing applies to the ROPC flow, again, no service involved but the CA policies are applied anyways.